# Google Chrome: Unable to select and scroll down simultaneously

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, mouse, scrolling, selection

When selecting text in Chrome, I am able to scroll up but I am not able to scroll down, while the selection is going on. What I mean is that when I select text that is larger than the page showing on screen, I am able to select that text and continue selecting text going upwards, but not going downwards. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? 
I'm on windows 8 and using Chrome version 44.0.2403.125 m.

Thanks,

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BoarsOZwfYU check this out

Comment: Thanks, but is solution for Windows 7. Edited my question to specify windows 8.

Comment: That solution should work in Windows 8 as well, they aren't that different. Try it and let us know if it worked.